# visual studio plugin/automator - object field mapper

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, mapping

I'm aware of automapper and various other methods of mapping fields from one object to another, but I'm curious if this tool exists: something that within visual studio, one could run a plugin that would spit out "best guess" mapping between two classes, as inline code. ie, instead of having to type out:

```
obj1.fname = obj2.fname;
obj1.lname = obj2.lname;
obj1.address = obj2.address;
...
```

One could run a plugin that spits out this code inline by simply looking at field names and matching up the ones that are the same name? My reason for wanting to do this inline is that it could spit out the majority of the logic, and then I could easily add any additonal values or handle any non-direct mapping work.

I find that so much of my coding these days is doing this kind of boring mapping between two objects, of either the same or of different types.

Comment: Use entity framework? (Microsoft or 3rd party)

Comment: the objects are not necessarily of the same type. so clone will not work. and entity framework might be one of the objects, but the second one could be something else.

Comment: I've heard of mapping tools that do this now, I'll update with them when I find again

Comment: Wow, just googled this same topic and found my old post on here again ;)